# Move To Next Table in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

My html is:

```
<div class="board">
  <table id="mastermind_table_one">
     <td></td> # background color is green
     <td></td> # background color is blue
     <td></td> # background color is yellow
     <td></td> # background color is purple
 </table>

# I click the 'next_round' button and the function moves on to the next table

 <table id="mastermind_table_two">
     <td></td> # background color is yellow
     <td></td> # background color is orange
     <td></td> # background color is blue
     <td></td> # background color is green
 </table>

 # I click the 'next_round' button and the function moves on to the next table

 <table id="mastermind_table_three">
     <td></td> # background color is purple
     <td></td> # background color is blue
     <td></td> # background color is orange
     <td></td> # background color is yellow
 </table>
```

and so on...

I have a function I created that randomly fills the background color of a table. The problem lies in getting the next table filled when I click the same "next_round" button. Right now, I have 3 separate click events (on the same button) for each of the tables and it's repetitive and wasteful.

Can this be done?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D3zyt/8/ (you'll see that it only fills the second row. I was hoping to have it move on to the next row...)

Comment: Could you please provide your JavaScript, or better yet a fiddle?

Comment: Sorry, here is the js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D3zyt/8/

Comment: I'm not exactly understanding your goal: Do you want to have all rows be randomized at the same time? Or do you want to loop through each row on each click (only one row colored at each time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var current_table=0;
    var tables=$("table");

    //your code
    $('.next_round').click(function() {
        $(tables[current_table]).each(function() {
          $(this).find('td').each(function() {
            $(this).css("background-color", setRandomColor);
          })
        })
        if(current_table < tables.length){
            current_table++;
        }    
   })
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! This works well (just tried it).